# Is there any difference between void f(Class c) and void f(Class<?> c) in Java?

Tags: java, generics, methods, overloading, method-signature

The following Java code cannot be compiled with an error: **Names conflict**.

```
class Test {

    public void f(Class<?> c) {
    }

    public void f(Class c) {
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between `void f(Class c)` and void `f(Class<?> c)` in Java?

Comment: Semantically, one's generic and explicitly wild, the other's non-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declared in the same class, they are override-equivalent and will cause a compilation error.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.

where

> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1
>   is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

and

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - **the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.**

The bolded case is the problem here.

The erasure of `Class<?>` is `Class`.

> Is there any difference between void f(Class c) and void f(Class c) in Java?

From a caller's perspective, no. Within the body of the method, yes. In the first case, the parameter has the [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) `Class`. In the second case, the parameter has the parameterized type `Class<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `?` is a wild-card which can be used with parametrized classes/interfaces. For example `Collection<Object>` is a generic collection which contains items of type `Object` whereas `Collection<?>` is a super type of all types of collections.